# How to replace value inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as shown below.

```
array (size=2)
    '1S1' =>
      array (size=8)
        'order_id' => int 0
        'item_id' => int 1
        'special_desc' => string 'Special XXX' (length=11)
        'qty' => int 2
        'price' => int 50
        'amount' => int 0
        'created_at' => int 1376580193
        'updated_at' => int 1376580193
    '1S2' =>
      array (size=8)
        'order_id' => int 0
        'item_id' => int 2
        'special_desc' => string 'Special YYY' (length=11)
        'qty' => int 3
        'price' => int 150
        'amount' => int 0
        'created_at' => int 1376580193
        'updated_at' => int 1376580193
```

If I wanted to replace "order_id" of both elements of this array to a new value before saving to the database, what array function or technique can I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the array dynamic in which, you wouldn't know the keys to the first level?

Comment: What's wrong with looping through your array and modifing the variables directly?

Comment: just loop through your array eg. with foreach and modify your value

Comment: Sorry, I thought image is easy to read, I didn't know people copies the code somewhere to help fixing my problem. Thanks Cris for image to text conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array = array_walk( $array, function( $subArray ) {
    $subArray[ 'order_id' ] = 'someNewValue';
} );
```

A simple `foreach` could work too.

```
// Noting the '&' by reference call
foreach( $array as &$subArray ) {
    $subArray[ 'order_id' ] = 'someNewValue';
}
// Or
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
   $array[ $key  ][ 'order_id' ] = 'someNewValue';
}
```

Comment: The correct function to use in this situation is [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk), not `array_map` (your function doesn’t return anything).

Comment: I use for each but the values did not change.
$cartItems = array_values($cartItems);
foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
  $cartItem['order_id'] = 50;
}
var_dump($cartItems);

Comment: @Kongthap you need to specify that you are editing it `by reference`. Thats what the `&` is for in front of my `$subArray` is. Change your foreach to `foreach( $cartItems as &$cartItem )`

Comment: @Kongthap I added another way to do a foreach for you, that doesnt use `by reference`

Comment: Using $array['1S1']['order_id'] = $new_value is working, but I have to loop through the whole array at runtime.

Comment: @Ascherer I got it now, sorry for my poor PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_name['1S1']['order_id'] = some value;
$array_name['1S2']['order_id'] = some value;
```

Comment: This is why I specificly asked the OP if the first level array keys were dynamic in which case this won't work :p You would have to loop

Comment: Sorry, looping through the whole array is better for my case, but I still cannot get value changed using foreach.

Comment: Your answer is working for changing to the new value but I don't understand why 
foreach ($entireArray as $eachArray) {
  $eachArray['order_id'] = $new_value;
}
is not working...